# Are equicontinuous function dominated by a continuous function?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $f_n: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ be an equicontinuous sequence of functions. Does there exist a continuous function $f$ that dominates $f_n $ in the following sense?

We say $f$ dominates the sequence $f_n$ if for all $x \in [0, 1]$, if $\delta > 0, \varepsilon > 0$ are such that $\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert < \varepsilon$ for all $y$ such that $\lvert x - y\rvert < \delta$, then also for all $n$, $\lvert f_n (x) - f_n (y)\rvert < \varepsilon$ for all $y$ such that $\lvert x - y\rvert < \delta$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is well known that if $(f_n)$ are equicontinuous on a compact space, then they are uniformly equicontinuous. Let $\omega(\delta)=\sup\{|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\colon
|x-y|\le\delta; n\in\mathbb N\}$ be the modulus of continuity of the family, so that $\omega(\delta)\to 0$ as $\delta\to 0$. I will assume without loss of generality that the $(f_n)$ take values in $[0,1]$.

Then we will construct a continuous function $f$ whose modulus of continuity exceeds $\omega(\delta)$, so that it dominates $(f_n)$ in your sense. The idea is pretty simple: sum together a bunch of periodic functions that are mostly zero, but have steeper and steeper spikes (of decreasing heights).

Let $\delta_1>\delta_2>\ldots$ be such that $\omega(\delta)<4^{-k}$ whenever $\delta<\delta_k$. Then we inductively build functions $g_k$ for $k=1,\ldots$ such that $g_k$ is periodic of period $\delta_{k+1}$ and on each period is zero, followed by a linear branch up to height $4^{1-k}$ followed by a linear branch of the same length back to 0. We let the length of each of the two linear branches be $\ell_k$, which is chosen to be sufficiently small that the sum of the maximal variations of $g_1$, $g_2$, $\ldots$, $g_{k-1}$ over an interval of length $\ell_k$ is at most $4^{-k}$.

Finally let $f=\sum g_k$. I claim this function has the required property. In particular, it is suffices to show that if $\omega(\delta)=\epsilon$, then there exist $x,y\in [0,1]$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|>\epsilon$.

Suppose that $\delta_{k+1}\le \delta<\delta_k$. Then $\omega(\delta)<4^{-k}$ and we will exhibit $x,y$ such that $|x-y|\le \delta_{k+1}$, but $|f(x)-f(y)|>4^{-k}$.
In particular, we choose $x$ and $y$ to be the left and right end points of an increasing interval of $g_k$ with $g_k(x)=0$ and $g_k(y)=4^{1-k}=4\cdot 4^{-k}$. By assumption, $$
\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} |g_j(x)-g_j(y)|\le 4^{-k}.
$$
Also
$$
\sum_{j=k+1}^\infty |g_j(x)-g_j(y)|\le \sum_{j=k+1}^\infty 4^{1-j}=\tfrac 43\cdot 4^{-k}.
$$

It follows that
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\ge |g_k(x)-g_k(y)|-\tfrac 734^{-k}>4^{-k}
$$
as required.

Comment: Very nice!  I was up late last night trying to work out the [idea](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391757/are-equicontinuous-function-dominated-by-a-continuous-function#comment999251_391761) of constructing an $f$ that's ‘worse’ than any given modulus of continuity, but I couldn't make it go.

Comment: Thank you for this! I’ve been stuck on this question for awhile too.

Comment: Could you add some details justifying the statement that 'it suffices to show that if $\omega(\delta) = \epsilon$, then there exist $x,y \in [0,1]$ such that [...]'? Given the choice of quantifiers in the definition of domination, would you not instead have to prove something akin to for all $x \in [0,1]$ there is $y \in [0,1]$ with $\lvert x - y \rvert < \delta$ and $\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert > \epsilon$?

Comment: @LeoMoos, the quantifier in the original question is over all $x \in [0, 1]$, so the negation should indeed be existential in $x$, right?

Comment: For what it’s worth you could make an $\epsilon$ modification to the argument to get for all $x$. You let $x$ be given and then choose $y$ such that $g_k(y)$ is as far from $g_k(x)$ as possible within a single period. You’re guaranteed to get at least $2\times4^{-k}$. You would need to play with the constants a bit to make this work (certainly changing 4 to 10 should do the trick).

Answer (score 2):

Let $\omega$ be a continuously differentiable [modulus of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity) for $(f_n)_n$.  EDIT:  I meant this in the stronger sense that $\omega'$ extends to a continuous function on $[0, 1]$, which might not be possible.  So this is only a partial answer.

Let $M = \sup \{\omega'(t) \mathrel: t \in [0, 1]\}$, and put $f(x) = M x$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.  Then, for all $x, y \in [0, 1]$ with $x \ne y$, we have that $\frac{\omega(\lvert x - y\rvert)}{\lvert x - y\rvert} = \omega'(t) \le M$ for some $0 < t < \lvert x - y\rvert$, so $\omega(\lvert x - y\rvert) \le M\lvert x - y\rvert = \lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert$.

Fix $x, y \in [0, 1]$ with $x \ne y$, and $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert < \varepsilon$.  Then also $\omega(\lvert x - y\rvert) < \varepsilon$, so $\lvert f_n(x) - f_n(y)\rvert < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Hm, if you want $\omega$ to be continuously differentiable, is it always possible to have $\omega(0) = 0$? There are functions with Holder moduli of continuity if I’m not mistaken..

Comment: I am not an expert, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity) requires $\omega(0) = 0$, and [claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity#Remarks) that any modulus of continuity can be smoothed.

Comment: Ah, yeah it should be smoothable, but then I think $\sup \omega’$ would be $\infty$ even after smoothing, since a function with a Holder modulus of continuity would have derivative of $\omega$ unbounded on $(0, \epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon$. (More precisely $\omega’ \to \infty$ near $0$).

Comment: Ah, I think you’re right.  I suspect that the argument can be adapted by using a more complicated $f$, but don’t immediately see how, so will just leave this partial answer for now.  Essentially, I mean to construct a function that “does worse” than any specified modulus of continuity.

Comment: (In other words, given $\omega$, construct $f$ so the optimal modulus of continuity of $f$ is bounded below by $\omega$.)

Comment: That actually gives some ideas for a “counterexample”. More precisely, a counterexample when the equicontinuous set of functions is uncountable. Like you should be able to arrange for every point to have an “at best” Holder modulus of continuity, and then it should be impossible to construct a continuous function with such a bad modulus of continuity at every point. However in the case where the set is only countable as in the question, you can only arrange for countably many bad points and so it doesn’t rule out the possibility yet.

Comment: @NateRiver I am not sure your counterexample will work, e.g. the Weierstrass-function is a single continuous function whose modulus of continuity is only Hölder at every point.

Comment: Oh that’s true..